# Group By and Groups of Groups in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I am trying to write a query in MS Access using group by that results in the count of two groups and then the count of the remaining groups combined.

So if I have a field color and 18 items and I do a count of items group by color I would have the following results:

```
red = 6
green = 3
orange = 2
blue = 3
yellow = 4
```

However, what I'm looking for is the following:

```
red = 6
green = 3
All other colors = 9
```

Not sure how to code the sql for this.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CntColor, Switch([Color]="Red","Red",[Color]="Green","Green",True,"Other") AS ColorGrp
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Switch([Color]="Red","Red",[Color]="Green","Green",True,"Other");
```

Comment: When I run this groups with zero values do not show.  for example, if no values were green my results would be `Red: 6, All other colors: 12`.  How do I get `Red: 6, Green: 0, All Other colors: 12`.  Thanks

Comment: Need to join to a dataset that has all desired colors. Do you have a master table of colors?

Comment: No.  Colors are in the main table.  What would be in the color table (other than colors of course)

Comment: Probably just one field with all colors or at least the 2 you want to always show.